# Spark Structured Streaming with Azure EventHub

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, azure-eventhub

In the context of Spark Streaming with Azure EventHub, technically i need some help in understanding the differrence b/w EventPosition.fromStartOfStream, EventPosition.fromEndOfStream. If i need to trigger the Streaming job only once a day with checkpointing enabled, what difference will the below code do.

Gone through couple of docs, couldn't find much information on this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
val ehConf = EventHubsConf(cs).setStartingPositions(positions).setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromStartOfStream)

val ehConf = EventHubsConf(cs).setStartingPositions(positions).setStartingPosition(EventPosition.fromEndOfStream)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checkpointing then position given by setStartingPosition won't have any use. it is only used if there is no checkpoint found.

Please see sample code and description here - https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/564267dd1287b0593f8914b1acf8ff7796b58e3b/docs/spark-streaming-eventhubs-integration.md#per-partition-configuration